# Joomla User Login show specific User Files

Tags: joomla

does anyone know of a simple module or extension etc for Joomla that would enable the admin to upload a file relevant to a specific user login?

For example, they have a bunch of user accounts, and would like a registered area on the website that would show files relevant to only that user credentials.

In the backend, they would easily like to add a document and select which user can see it.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out the "Component Access Permission" extension, [here](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/access-a-security/site-access/backend-a-full-access-control/13524)